# javascript code giving different values in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

As I was trying to center a drop down menu, I recieved a javascript code that would do the job, but the problem is what it gives me different values in dreamweaver/IE from chrome/firefox.
This is a piece of the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("nav ul ul").each(function () {
        var navWidth = $(this).width();
        var liWidth = $(this).closest("li").width();
        var gaps = navWidth - liWidth; 
        alert(gaps);
    });
});
```

In dreamweaver I would get 25, -86 and -163, but in chrome, I get 54, -34 and -88.

Comment: How about this? Different browsers have different HTML rendering preset values for `li`'s *(and many other stuff)*

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: override them through CSS, haven't done it before but I'm 99% it would be a breeze

Comment: Just use a [CSS reset](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=css%20reset), it will normalize default browser values, like margins and paddings. Include a stylesheet like this before your own css styles.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of CSS reset. See, [Meyer's CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) reset for example.

However, do note that despite the CSS reset, there can be very small difference in the value's obtained. Here 's a jsFiddle link to demonstrate that :

http://jsfiddle.net/5pa4t8xp/2/

This is the code I used (*there is also a reference to Meyer's reset*) :-

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>Hi</li>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>How</li>
    <li>is</li>
    <li>your</li>
    <li>day?</li>
</ul>

<div class="answer"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:normal;
}

.answer {
    border:1px solid Black;
    margin:20px auto;
    padding: 5px;
    line-height:1.5;
    width:80%;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul li').each(function() {
        var liWidth = $(this).width();
        var liContent = $(this).html();
        //alert(liWidth);
        //alert(liContent);
        $('.answer').append('<div>The width of ' + liContent + ' is ' + liWidth + '</div>');
    });
});
```

You can see the difference in values below that I observed[image]

**EDIT** : As the first part of your question belies your specific problem, without giving the much needed `HTML` code, I'd suggest to make use of the 
`text-align: center` property in `CSS` to center your drop-down menu. Depending on the html structure, you may also be able to achieve this using `margin: 0 auto` trick.

***I'd suggest using the aforementioned CSS approach rather than the approach you seem to be taking since, as I illustrate in the example above, this approach can yield inconsistent results.***